# Setting PowerApps CustomConnector to OAuth2/AzureAD

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, powerapps

I am trying to use OAuth2 (Azure Active Directory) to authenticate against a web api that I wrote, which is secured by Azure Active Directory. I know my security is setup correctly because I wrote a different app to consume the API, and it works.

When I try to setup the PowerApps custom connector, I keep getting a 401 Unauthorized error. I believe that it is because I don't have my settings correct. However, I cannot figure out what the fields in the PowerApps security page are supposed to map to.

Here is a screen shot of the page in powerapps. Please advise...
[image: Security Tab for Custom Connector]
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client id and client secrecy is that the property the client app you register in the app.

And the resource URL is the app id URI of the app which represents the web API. And you can decode it from the token which works for previews request.

More detail about authentication for the PowerApps for Azure Active Directory, you can refer the link below:

[Use Azure Active Directory with a custom connector in PowerApps](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/tutorials/customapi-azure-resource-manager-tutorial/)